# Azure app service php session id duplicated

Tags: php, azure, session, azure-web-app-service

On Azure Linux App service, PHP 7.4, with ARR Affinity was enabled, sometimes different client will get same session id, how to fix it?

| time | session id | ip |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023/02/17 09:21:00 | c3afe305bd82d13d532d18a1e29c0ab0fbfe51365c7fbf6 | 1.163.94.12 |
| 2023/02/17 09:21:14 | c3afe305bd82d13d532d18a1e29c0ab0fbfe51365c7fbf6 | 1.163.94.12 |
| 2023/02/17 09:21:19 | c3afe305bd82d13d532d18a1e29c0ab0fbfe51365c7fbf6 | 1.163.94.12 |
| 2023/02/17 09:21:25 | c3afe305bd82d13d532d18a1e29c0ab0fbfe51365c7fbf6 | 1.163.94.12 |
| 2023/02/17 09:28:10 | c3afe305bd82d13d532d18a1e29c0ab0fbfe51365c7fbf6 | 106.64.41.90 |
| 2023/02/17 09:28:11 | c3afe305bd82d13d532d18a1e29c0ab0fbfe51365c7fbf6 | 106.64.41.90 |
| 2023/02/17 09:28:13 | c3afe305bd82d13d532d18a1e29c0ab0fbfe51365c7fbf6 | 1.163.94.12 |

Comment: Are you sure that just isn't a mobile device moving around swapping connections? The times seem pretty close.

Comment: We use session to keep member id and name, and many members feedback had seen another member's name when browse website, so we logged session content and client IP try to fix this bug.

This situation never happened before we moved our website to Azure App service.